# Display the same content in UITableView included in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I have an issue with UITableView inserted in a UITableViewCell. This is my custom cell:
[image]
Everything works fine for the first, second and third cells, but from the fourth cell for the content of the UITableView inserted in cell is used always the same rows of the first, second and third cells alternatively. Instead the labels outside the UITableView are correctly displayed in every cells. This is my code for the custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

class SimulazioneQuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let cellIdentifier = "simRisposteCell"
    var arrayRisposte = [Risposta]()

    @IBOutlet var numeroLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var domandaLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var risposteTableView: UITableView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        var nib = UINib(nibName: "SimulazioneQuestionAnswerTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.risposteTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayRisposte.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as SimulazioneQuestionAnswerTableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayRisposte[indexPath.row].testo

        return cell
    }

}
```

And this is my view controller:

```
import UIKit


class SimulazioneViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var areaSimulazione: Int = Int()
    var arrayDomande = [Domanda]()
    var arrayRisposte = [[Risposta]]()
    var cellIdentifier = "domandaSimulazioneCell"


    @IBOutlet var tempoTrascorso: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var simulazioneTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrayDomande = ModelManager.instance.getSimulazione(area: areaSimulazione)

        var nib = UINib(nibName: "SimulazioneQuestionTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.simulazioneTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayDomande.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: SimulazioneQuestionTableViewCell = simulazioneTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.cellIdentifier) as SimulazioneQuestionTableViewCell
        var domanda: Domanda = arrayDomande[indexPath.row]
        var rispXDomanda = ModelManager.instance.getAnswersForQuestion(domanda.numero)
        cell.numeroLabel.text = String(domanda.numero)
        cell.domandaLabel.text = domanda.testo
        cell.arrayRisposte = rispXDomanda

        return cell
    }
```

Some advice to resolve this issue?

Thank you guys!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to display a question with a list of possible answers underneath?
Are you showing more than one question at a time on screen?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly as you said. Is shown completely only the first question and partially the second when the view appears. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had the idea of putting a `UITableView` inside a `UITableViewCell` and therefore would have approached this from a different direction. I'm not saying the table inside a cell is impossible or a bad idea, but the following approach might actually be easier.

My understanding is that your table view shows a number of questions, and each question has possible answer right below it.

I'd use one section per question, with the first row using a custom cell that shows the `numeroLabel` and the `domandaLabel` (basically `SimulazioneQuestionTableViewCell` without the table), and then put the answers into the remaining rows for the section.

```
private let QuestionCellIdentifier = "QuestionCell"
private let AnswerCellIdentifier = "AnswerCell"

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return arrayDomande.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  let rispXDomanda = ModelManager.instance.getAnswersForQuestion(domanda.numero)
  return 1 + rispXDomanda.count // one extra for the question
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let domanda = arrayDomande[indexPath.section]

  switch indexPath.row {
  case 0:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(QuestionCellIdentifier) as SimulazioneQuestionTableViewCell
    cell.numeroLabel.text = String(domanda.numero)
    cell.domandaLabel.text = domanda.testo
    return cell
  default:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AnswerCellIdentifier) as SimulazioneQuestionAnswerTableViewCell
    let rispXDomanda = ModelManager.instance.getAnswersForQuestion(domanda.numero)
    cell.textLabel?.text = rispXDomanda[indexPath.row - 1].testo
    return cell
  }
```

It might be a good idea to cache the answers that you get from `ModelManager`. It depends on how expensive it is to get them - with the code above `getAnswersForQuestion()` will be called a lot.

Edit: I personally like the `.Grouped` style for the table view. Using a section per question will nicely separate them visually.

Comment: Wonderful! Thomas Müller you are a great man! Your code works perfectly. I cached the answers not only to improve execution speed but even because `getAnswersForQuestion()` every time returns the answers randomly ordered and so it may happen that the same answer may appear on multiple rows under the question. Thank you so much, thank you so much indeed!       Edit: `.Grouped` is awesome for the TableView!